# C# - "Cross-thread operation not valid" error during connectivity event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events, thread-safety

I wrote a little bit of code for my WinForm app to display the connection state of the computer it is running on by changing a color-coded label control.

In my form I have the following code:

```
public frmShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.stateManager = new StateManager();
}

private void frmShell_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Subscribe to events
    this.stateManager.ConnectionChange += new StateManager.ConnectionChangeHandler(ConnectionHasChanged);
}

private void ConnectionHasChanged(object sender, ConnectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.Network)
    {
        if (e.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            SetLabelOnline();
        }
        else
        {
            SetLabelOffline();
        }
    }
}
private void SetLabelOffline()
{
    labelConnectivityValue.Text = "Offline";
    labelConnectivityValue.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

private void SetLabelOnline()
{
    labelConnectivityValue.Text = "Online";
    labelConnectivityValue.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Every time I disable my network adapter to test my code I get the followig error in the *SetLabelOnline()* or *SetLabelOffline()* method:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'labelConnectivityValue' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

**1. I fail to understand why my code would be considered an invalid cross-thread operation. Furthermore, I am simply re-using code that I used earlier in another WinForm app in precisely the same way.**

**2. I have no idea how one would go about solving this issue, especially considering that what I'm trying to achieve seems pretty basic.**

Note: the code in the statemanager is simply a timer that checks every so often for the state of the connection and fire the event when the connection property has to be changed i.e. if the connection state has changed

Comment: What kind of timer does `StateManager` use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timer, or whatnot, that is firing that event is doing it from a different thread than the one owning the form (and all its controls).

This may have "worked" in an earlier version of WinForms, in the sense that the explicit checks that are now throwing exceptions wasn't there. It didn't work *correctly*, however, which is why those checks was added, to help people figure out that they have a problem.

There's two ways to handle this:

1. Ensure the code that invokes the event is not using a secondary thread. You're mentioning a timer, it could be that this code is using the wrong type of timer, by mistake. You should look into that.

   If the code is using [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), verify if it can use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead. This second timer uses the messaging system that the Winforms system is built upon, which will invoke the events on the same thread that owns the form and its controls.
2. Ensure the code in the event can cope with being executed on a different thread.

The correct way to do this (ie. point 2 above) is to marshal each call over to the same thread that is owning the form and its controls, you can do this by changing the header of each such method as follows:

```
private void ConnectionHasChanged(object sender, ConnectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ConnectionHasChanged(sender, e);
        }));
        return;
    }

    if (e.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.Network)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Gah! How stupid of me! Indeed I was using System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Windows.Forms.Timer. That fixed the issue right away! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the solution to your problem lies in the last paragraph you wrote.
You said that your using a Timer in StateManager.

There are 3 types of common Timers in the .NET framework:

1. System.Timers.Timer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
2. System.Threading.Timer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
3. System.Windows.Forms.Timer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

The first two timers are using Threads to do their work and are not thread safe. The last one, the Forms.Timer is the preferred way of using timers when dealing with WinForms.

You have two options:

1. Make sure that the StateManager timer is a WinForm timer.
2. Make use of InvokeRequired method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx To understand if you are on the right thread.

Comment: As stated above, I was indeed not using the forms Timer. Thanks!